# Is there a way to link two values in two separate list boxes together?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I'm building a small application that takes accepts as inputs information describing Students and Advisers. I've created a class for each and once the information is inputted both objects are stored in separate listboxes. The problem is that I then have to link instances of the student class to instances of the Adviser class, and I have no idea where to even begin. Each student can only have 1 adviser but an adviser can work with many students.

I'm thinking that I'll have to create an ID# for advisers as right now I only collect string information from them, and using a number might be easier. I'm new to object-oriented programming. Where should I begin?

Comment: Have you already set the datasource of your listbox? And are just trying to combine the info?

Comment: The data doesn't need to be stored once the application is no longer running, so I'm just trying to associate the two values temporarily. Once all the info of each object is described (first name, last name, major, department), they're stored in a listbox. Once the info is stored all I have to do is be able to select a given value in the listbox and have all it's characteristics displayed in another part of the form. Fairly straightforward, with the exception of assigning multiple students to an adviser and then having that info display on demand.

Comment: Why would you assign students to an advisor and not store that information?

Comment: The application isn't being built for real-world use, just an exercise in some programming concepts, otherwise I would most certainly store the information. I have 0 experience in storing the entered information to a small database, although if it's fairly straightforward to do I might as well look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq will help you join your classes together.

```
    private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var joined = (from s in Students
                          join a in Advisers on s.AdvisorsID equals a.AdvisorsID 
                          where a.AdvisorsID == ((Advisor)ListBox1.SelectedItem).AdvisorID
                          select new {a, s});
        }
    }
```

This will give you an object that you can loop through or use as a datasource for a UI object.

You will need some common field to join them together however.  Using @Ryans answer about relational data is helpful if you are pulling your information from / to a database.

EDIT: 
I just noticed `Listbox` in the title.  The [customary way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this is to have a datasource that has an ID and a text value.

Set the datasource:

```
listbox.DataSource = Students;
```

The ID is set to the Listbox's ValueMember property:

```
listbox.ValueMember = "StudentID";
```

And then to the display value respectively:

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "StudentName";
```

Then you can use my LINQ code above to pull the correct one out of the structures.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to Linq, this looks like what I'll have to do.

Comment: @cjharty Great, let me know if anything is unclear.  Please remember to mark your answer. (the checkbox below the vote count)

Answer (score 1):

You're going down the right path.  I'm assuming that these objects will get stored in some kind of persistant storage one day (like a database), right?

If so, then add a primary key to each of your objects.  Say StudentID for your student objects and AdviserID for your Advisers.  Then, add an AdviserID column *to the Student object*.  This will map Students to Advisers in a N..1 relationship.

If these objects are never going to be persisted to a database, then just add a collection of Students to your Adviser object.  For example, your Adviser object could have the following object property:

```
public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

Make sense?

Comment: They're not going to be stored in a database, they just need to be active while the form is running. I was thinking of using lists within the form to store all instances of students and another for all instances of advisers. Is there a way to make a sublist within a list to assign particular students to particular advisers? Or would I be better off making a completely separate list within the student and adviser classes themselves?

Comment: I'd maintain a list of Advisers in the form and add the List<Student> Students property as I noted above to the Advisers class.  This will make binding interface elements to an Adviser's collection of Students easier.

Alternatively, you could maintain a List of Students, a List of Advisers, and a Dictionary<Adviser, List<Student>> mapping Advisers to a List of Students.

I'd suggest the first option, though.